# change text of material chip

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-chips

I have a chip group in which chips are being added dynamically. I have to change chip text when text of chip matches "Choose date". But on deselecting the chip the chip text should be replaced with the original text.

But i am unable to find the chip id when it is deselected.
I am using below code for doing same. Please suggest how can i do this.

```
   chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup chipGroup, int i) {

            chipchoose = chipGroup.findViewById(i);
            if (chipchoose != null){
            String chipnamee= chipchoose.getText().toString();
            if (chipnamee.equalsIgnoreCase("Choose Date")){
                openDialogCalender();
            }
        }
        }


    });
```

chipchoose is null when chip is deselected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the `Chip` programatically you can add for each `Chip` a listener.
Something like:

```
    chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chip, isChecked ->
        if (!isChecked){
            //....chip.text = "...." //replace the text
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried a different approach. When the chip is deselected i remove all the views of chipgroup and then add all of it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Listener` on `ChipGroup` can only listen to **Checked** state, for listening **Unchecked** state set `Listener` on target `Chip`.